# how to download zip files from webview into iphone?

Tags: iphone

I plan to let users download their own files and stored them inside iPhone. The process is typically:

- app file into cloud app convert zip file.
- iPhone present a web page by UIWebView, in which there are one link to .zip files
  the user browser the page and click on one of the .zip file link
  *download zip file in cloud app ,how to open?
  *zip file download in iphone device possible or not possible,
  any body know help me!

Answer (score 0):

1/ Declare a delegate for your webview.
2/ Implement ShouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

3/ return NO in this delegate, but use the request url to download the zip file using NSURLConnection.
4/Use a zip library to decompress the zip file.
For example [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/).

Answer (score 0):

Check [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

*"ASIHTTPRequest is an easy to use wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications."*

Look for: *"Using gzip to handle compressed response data"*